How to change the titles of the Create and Update resource pages?
I know how to add the title of a custom resource in Filament - it just requires a header label. So I added this to my "UserResource.php":
protected static ?string $label = 'Users';

Filament creates  create, edit and list pages for this resource. So I have  CreateUser, EditUser and ListUsers inside UserResource/Pages folder.
But how do I give the create and edit pages their own header title? Because by default these say "Create Users" and "Edit Users". I want it to say something else.

If you want to change the title, you can override title property on each respective page, for example, if you want to change the title on the Create Page, add this code to the CreateUser file:
protected static ?string $title = 'Create New User';

if you want the title to be dynamic, you can override getTitle function. For example, you can add this code to the CreateUser file:
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Htmlable;

public function getTitle(): string | Htmlable
{
    $text = auth()->user()->hasRole('admin') ? 'Create User' : 'View User';
    return $text;
}


If you want to change the title, you can override the modelLabel and pluralModelLabel properties on the respective page. For example, if you want to change the title on the Create and Update resource pages, add the following code to the relevant resource file:
protected static ?string $modelLabel = ' University';
protected static ?string $pluralModelLabel = 'Universities';

This will change the singular and plural titles displayed on the Create and Update pages for the resource.
